# More than one power bi report embedded into React application

Tags: reactjs, powerbi

I have created a react application with different tabs that display power bi reports that are embedded. When I mount and unmount each React component that has a power bi report, it works fine. When I don't unmount each component, the current power bi report that gets embedded replaces all the iframes with the other power bi reports. I have a different id for each iframe container to make sure each container is unique.

Are multiple embedded BI Reports supported?

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: How are these report embedded?